# Django models.py importing with no fields

Tags: django, sqlite

As I am working through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/ , in django, I have started a new app called `myapp` and edited the the `models.py` file as the walkthrough defines:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (u'M', u'Male'),
    (u'F', u'Female')
  )
  name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

Then I ran `manage.py syncdb` and tried to run the next few lines in the `manage.py shell` interactive prompt

```
>>> p = Person(name="Fred Flintstone", gender="M")
>>> p.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .…[I removed a few lines]...
  DatabaseError: table myapp_person has no column named name
>>> p.gender
u'M'
>>> p.get_gender_display()
u'Male'
```

...so then I checked to see if sqlite3 had an object in the database called Person with the name column

```
C:\Users\djangoSite>python manage.py sql myapp
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "myapp_person" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(60) NOT NULL,
"gender" varchar(2) NOT NULL
```

);

And of course it does! So the Person model exists, however it doesn't get the fields that I designed it with in models.py? I did a `dir(Person)` calls and it confirms that the name and gender fields aren't in there… secondly, I did `dir(p)` and it does have them. I suppose that is because we just added them in with that tuple, so that's not a surprise.

The big questions then are:

1. Why can't I 'p.save()'?
2. Why doesn't the import call bring in objects with the fields that I designed in `models.py`?
3. Is this by design?
4. Am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: use Person.objects.create() instead. should work ok.

Comment: After doing some more research, I found this little gem in the django documentation that seems to explain the problem: Syncdb will not alter existing tables syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes made to a model class after installation. Changes to model classes and database schemas often involve some form of ambiguity and, in those cases, Django would have to guess at the correct changes to make. There is a risk that critical data would be lost in the process. It was as you said delete the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I `p.save()`?

There is no column named name in your person table.  `manage.py sql myapp` just shows the sql that django generates based on your model.  Not the actual table in sqlite.  (of course it should match up)  It is important that you enter your sqlite database and verfiy the table and its schema.  I find that when developing I syncdb and make a change to the model later.  Re-syncing db doesn't modify the table.  You have to delete the table then resync, or alter table.

> Why doesn't the import call bring in objects with the fields that I designed in models.py?

Please modify your question to reflect this issue, it doens't look like you have any issues accessing or instantiating a person object.

> Is this by design?

No i don't think this is by design, I believe these are common issues that arise as a new user is learning a new framework.  I ran into all sorts of problems like these for weeks and months as I was learning, they will get farther and farther apart.  Just make sure you are verifying things work correctly.  Checking manage.py sql myapp isn't that relevant.  Checking your database to view the schem is more relevant.  Django is a mature platform and when it gives you an error like `missing colum`  99.9% of the time it means exactly that it is transparent.